# Regexp to match ads and not downloads

Tags: regex

I have this line to block advertisement hostnames like **ad.somedomain.tld**
but it seems to block hostnames like downloads, uploads, etc..

```
([\w.-]+\.)?ad\.[^/]+/?
```

What would be the right syntax, thanks

Comment: This question is not detailed enough, please give some precision:
- What kind of regular expression are you expecting?
- Do you have example of link that you want to match and not match?
- Finding a regexp matching all the ads website is not possible since new websites can show up, maybe you can start by matching the major ads providers as a first step.

Comment: Hello, just the regulat and standard REGEX. I am using privoxy, and would like to match subdomain names ONLY that look like ad.domain.com, ad2.domain.com, www.ad2.domain.com and so on..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [DEMO regex101](http://www.regex101.com/r/aV4yF7)

**Regex**

```
\b(?:.?)ad(?:.?)\b
```

***Description***

```
\b Word boundary: match in between (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
(?:.?) Non-capturing Group 
    . 0 to 1 times [greedy] Any character (except newline)
ad Literal ad
(?:.?) Non-capturing Group 
    . 0 to 1 times [greedy] Any character (except newline)
\b Word boundary: match in between (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
```

***Visualization*** (Provided by [debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/))

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. It does match all needed hosts, and allowed uploAD and downloAD hosts as well, thanks.

Comment: @RuslanAbuzant if you want you might want to do this http://www.regex101.com/r/aI0mY4 this allows for case insensitive.  this is an option in all regex handlers.